# PostgreSQL: Query that splits array of one element into multiple elements based on a delimiter and unnest it

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql, unnest

I am new to PostgreSQl and I am not able to find a solution to get the output mentioned below.

I have created a table with a column of data type text[], which is an array of text strings (single element).

My table looks like this:

```
col1       col2
ID1      {"P25963(MI:0326), Homo sapiens);O14920(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)"}
ID2      {"Q8NFZ0(MI:0326), Homo sapiens);P12931(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)"}
ID3      {"P26368(MI:0326), Homo sapiens);Q15637(MI:0326), Homo sapiens); Q15638(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)"}
```

When I try to access the first and second element of col2, I get below output.

```
SELECT col2[1] FROM table;

P25963(MI:0326), Homo sapiens);O14920(MI:0326), Homo sapiens
Q8NFZ0(MI:0326), Homo sapiens);P12931(MI:0326), Homo sapiens
P26368(MI:0326), Homo sapiens);Q15637(MI:0326), Homo sapiens); Q15638(MI:0326), Homo sapiens
```

```
SELECT col2[2] FROM table;

NULL
NULL
NULL
```

I would like to split this array element into multiple elements **(presence of ;)**, unnest them and later perform some regex on the unnested rows.

The desired output after splitting is:

```
col1       col2
ID1       {P25963(MI:0326), Homo sapiens},{O14920(MI:0326), Homo sapiens}
ID2       {Q8NFZ0(MI:0326), Homo sapiens},{P12931(MI:0326), Homo sapiens}
ID3       {P26368(MI:0326), Homo sapiens},{Q15637(MI:0326), Homo sapiens}, {Q15638(MI:0326), Homo sapiens}
```

The desired output after unnesting is:

```
col1     col3                                 col4   
ID1      P25963(MI:0326), Homo sapiens       O14920(MI:0326), Homo sapiens    
ID2      Q8NFZ0(MI:0326), Homo sapiens       P12931(MI:0326), Homo sapiens  
ID3      P26368(MI:0326), Homo sapiens       Q15637(MI:0326), Homo sapiens
ID3      P26368(MI:0326), Homo sapiens       Q15638(MI:0326), Homo sapiens
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: So each and every array contains a single element?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the original post for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just access the first element in the text array and use `split_part()` to get the underliying information:

```
select 
    col1,
    split_part(col2[1], ';', 1) col3,
    split_part(col2[1], ';', 2) col4
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6f5ecb1f972b7cd16835e2381b6925cb)**:

```
col1 | col3                           | col4                          
:--- | :----------------------------- | :-----------------------------
ID1  | P25963(MI:0326), Homo sapiens) | O14920(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID2  | Q8NFZ0(MI:0326), Homo sapiens) | P12931(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID3  | P26368(MI:0326), Homo sapiens) | Q15637(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
```

---

From the comments: if you want to split over a variable number of elements, I would recommend spreading the data into rows rather than columns. For this, you can use `string_to_array()` to split the string into an array, then `unnest()` to generate rows:

```
select
    t.col1,
    s.pos,
    s.val
from mytable t
cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t.col2[1], ';')) with ordinality s(val, pos)
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=448bc2231f21096093cd9ed7c1a60180)**:

```
col1 | pos | val                           
:--- | --: | :-----------------------------
ID1  |   1 | P25963(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID1  |   2 | O14920(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID2  |   1 | Q8NFZ0(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID2  |   2 | P12931(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID3  |   1 | P26368(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID3  |   2 | Q15637(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
ID3  |   3 | Q15638(MI:0326), Homo sapiens)
```

Comment: Can I split the array into n elements based on the presence of ; ? Please see ID3, it has 3 elements. Would be cumbersome if I do it for n elements

Comment: @ranusharma: you can add one more `split_part()` expression to get the third item (note that your expected output had only two additional columns). But if you want this to be dynamic, then you would rather spread the elements over rows than over columns (a SQL query must return a *fixed* set of columns).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. However I would like to spread it over column.

Comment: @ranusharma Spread by what criteria? You cannot have dynamic columns. At best, use an array column